# Does a redux saga for API requests make sense?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I wonder if a generic request saga makes any sense?

It would take a `REQUEST` action that contains all the infos like headers, url, data and would merge it with its own headers and base URL.
It would then `fetch` the request and then `put(REQUEST_SUCCEEDED, json)` with the json payload in the store.

```
const request = yield take(REQUEST)
const { url, data, headers } = request
try {
  if (request.startAction) {
    yield put(request.startAction)
  }
  const json = yield call(api.fetch, url, data, headers)
  yield put({...request.successAction, json})
} catch (error) {
  yield put({...request.errorAction, error})
}
```

As I understand it this would only allow one request at a time, so instead of calling the API fetch function a `fork` would be better?

The saga could also take care of managing the API `access_token` once it encounters it in the response headers and save it for all subsequent requests.

```
function getAction(action) {
  if (action) {
    if (typeof action === "string") {
      return { type: action }
    } else {
      return action
    }
  }
}

export function request(url, data, headers, actions) {
  let result = { 
    type: REQUEST,
    url, data, headers
  }
  actions[0] && result.startAction = getAction(actions[0])
  actions[1] && result.successAction = getAction(actions[1])
  actions[2] && result.errorAction = getAction(actions[2])
  return result
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several questions asked here.

- Yes. Generic request saga makes sense to me. A place to provide standard for all requests makes sense.
- Fork is most definitely needed. Or rather use `takeEvery` helper. This is to prevent missing some request while the saga is processing `fetch`. A default timeout may be needed to be implemented as well using `race`.
- The `actions` parameter in `request` function would be better to be object than array with keys of `startAction`. An alternative is to give request a name. And make generic suffix for each action (eg. GETSTH_START, GETSTH_SUCCESS, GETSTH_ERROR)